# A controller with this name is not registered

Tags: angularjs

I am working through some Angular examples and got an interesting exception-scenario & was wondering why it happens.

**The Scenario:**

IT FAILS
 - When I create my controller in a `$(document)ready(function{ ... })` block

IT WORKS
 - When I create my controller outright

**Why?**
I'm sure your not supposed to bring-in jQuery like this, but still, why does it fail?

**In The Head:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var appName = 'personal.web';
        var application = angular.module(appName, ['ngRoute']);

        application.config(function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $locationProvider) {

            // REQUIRED: Enables "late" registration
            application.register = {
                controller: $controllerProvider.register,
                directive: $compileProvider.directive,
                filter: $filterProvider.register,
                factory: $provide.factory,
                service: $provide.service
            };

            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
        });

        application.run(function ($http) {
            console.log(appName + ' is running');
        });
    </script>
```

**In The Body:**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="HomeIndexController">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Home Body</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" ng-view></div>
</div>
```

**At Page Bottom:**

FAILS: A controller with this name is not registered

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        application.controller('HomeIndexController', function ($scope) {

            var vm = this;

            console.log('HomeIndexController');
        });
    }); </script>
```

WORKS

```
application.controller('HomeIndexController', function ($scope) {

    var vm = this;

    console.log('HomeIndexController');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for it fails is `$(document).ready`, angular will register `controllers`, `services` and so on before rendering views. but here you are defining `controller` in `document.ready` which is too late that angular will throw error of cannot find controller.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because document is ready after angular has started, so your app is looking for a component that does not exist yet. and it fails...